# Remove elements from array if they appear an even number of times numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array like this:

```
A = [0,0,3,6,6,7,8,11,11,22]
```

And I want to remove the elements that appear an even number of times inside the array, so you get:

```
res = [3,7,8,22]
```

Is this possible using numpy?

Comment: Of course it is possible, was there a particular problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: well it's from another problem. I have an array with indexes from another array, which, for each time the index is present, needs to have that value multiplied by -1. but that didn't work for even values as it would only multiply once, so that's why I need to remove the indexes which appear an even number of times...

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. Maybe you should add more context to your question. See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need numpy for this type of array manipulation. I tried using pure python.

```
def removeevencountelements(listarg) :
    minelement = min(listarg)
    maxelement = max(listarg)
    uniqueelementsset = set(listarg)
    outputlist = [ ]
    for i in range(0 , len(uniqueelementsset)) :
        if ((listarg.count((list(uniqueelementsset)[i]))) % 2 == 1) :
            for i2 in range((listarg.count((list(uniqueelementsset)[i])))) :
                outputlist.append((list(uniqueelementsset)[i]))
    return outputlist
    
A = [1,1,1,2,2,3,5,7,8,9,10,10,10,10,12,12,12,15,1]
print(removeevencountelements(A))
```

Comment: This should work for now... the function isn't going to be called a lot so the performance increase numpy would bring should not be too big...

Comment: For odd occurrences the output list only has 1 of that element. So do you need the output list to contain all the odd occurrence of that element ? For example a list of [ 1 , 1 , 1 ] will output [ 1 ] currently. So if you want it to retain all the odd occurrence you need to multiply the push to output list by the occurrence count.

Comment: for each element, count the number of elements, if that number is odd, include the element in the output...

Comment: This now should make it that the input of [ 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 ] will result in an output of [ 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 ] and not [ 1 ]

Comment: If I misunderstood and you want only 1 odd output and not all the occurrence, just remove the i2 for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to implemet it, using a dictionary (only looping at most twice on all elements):

```
def f1(arr):
    result = []
    counter_dict = {}
    for num in arr:
        if num in counter_dict:
            counter_dict[num] += 1
        else:
            counter_dict[num] = 1

    for key in counter_dict:
        if counter_dict[key] % 2 == 1:
            result.append(key)
    return result
```

edit: If you need to keep all original appearances of the array then this works:

```
def f2(arr):
    result = []
    counter_dict = {}
    for num in arr:
        if num in counter_dict:
            counter_dict[num] += 1
        else:
            counter_dict[num] = 1

    for key in counter_dict:
        if counter_dict[key] % 2 == 1:
            result.extend([key]*counter_dict[key])
    return result
```

```
input: A = [0,0,3,6,6,7,8,11,11,22,22,22]
output f1: [3,7,8,22]
output f2: [3,7,8,22,22,22]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple way to accomplish this:

```
resultArray = [a for a in arr if arr.count(a) % 2 != 0]
```

where 'arr' is your original array.